# How to force custom permissions on files created by git checkout command?

Tags: git, file-permissions

I need files created by `git checkout` command to have custom permissions.

Even with `core.sharedrepository=0777` setting git creates working tree files with 0644 permissions. But I want it to be at least 0664 so someone from the group could write to them (it also would be very good to specify a custom owner group)

Applying recursively chown/chmod may work but it smells like the last resort and resource waste.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use just git to manage the file permissions of an installed tree.

git is single user. It does not track file ownership and permissions sufficient to secure a multiple user system.  Even if a simple tree wide `core.sharedrepository` with one user were sufficient for your use case, you are having difficulty getting it do what you want. Possibly its still using the default of `umask` ?

Consider a real archive format, either a software package system, or generic archive like tar. Get the permissions correct in the scripts that generate the archives.

Or, running a permissions fix script isn't that bad. If desired, check permissions prior to changing them, to avoid unnecessary changes to file metadata.

---

Unrelated consideration: if this tree is going to be updated, be aware that git doesn't sync files, it merges histories.  Understand [these git deployment rules](https://gitolite.com/deploy.html) to appreciate why scripting just `git pull` is probably wrong.